# Operação Logica em C

Tags: c

Estou tentando fazer um programa para verificar se uma determinada palavra é um Palíndromo. Estou com problemas em uma operação logica que não esta retornando o que eu esperava.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


#define bool    short
#define true    1
#define false   0
#define equals(a, b) (((strcmp(a, b) == 0 ) ? true : false))
#define NUMENTRADA 1000
#define TAMLINHA   1000


bool isFim (char* s){

    return (strlen(s) >= 3 && s[0] == 'F' && s[1] == 'I' && s[2] == 'M');

}


bool isPalindromo(char* s){

    int meio = strlen(s)/2;
    int indc = strlen(s) - 1;

    bool resp = true;    

//    printf("\nresp ==>> %d \n", resp);

    for (int i = 0 ; i < meio ; i++){

//        printf("\nresp2 ==>> %d \n", resp);       
//        printf("BOOL2  ======= >> %d \n", (resp && (s[i] == s[indc])));

        resp = resp && (s[i] == s[indc]);        
        indc--;

//        printf("VALOR  ======= >> %c \n", s[i]);
//        printf("VALOR 2  ======= >> %c \n", s[indc]);

//        printf("\nRESP  ======= >> %d \n", resp);
//        printf("BOOL  ======= >> %d \n", (resp && (s[i] == s[indc])));

    }

//        printf("\n---------------------------\n");
//        printf("BOOL  ======= >> %d \n", (s[i] == s[indc]));
//        printf("\n---------------------------\n");

    return resp;

}


int main (int argc, char** argv){

    char entrada [NUMENTRADA][TAMLINHA];
    int numEntrada = 0;

    do{

        fgets(entrada[numEntrada], TAMLINHA, stdin);

    } while (isFim(entrada[numEntrada++]) == false);

    numEntrada--;

    for (int i = 0; i < numEntrada ; i++){

        if(isPalindromo(entrada[i]) == true){

            printf("SIM\n");

        } else {

            printf("NAO\n");

        }

    }

}
```

Bom a operação:

```
resp = resp && (s[i] == s[indc]);
```

esta me retornando sempre falso (0) e não entendi o porque.

As palavras estão sendo inseridas no programa por redirecionamento de entrada. Segue uma parte do arquivo.in de entrada:

```
aça
acaçá
Ada
afã
aia
ala
ama
Ana
anilina
ara
arara
asa
ata
aviva
ele
esse
mamam
mamam
matam
metem
oco
omissíssimo
Omo
osso
Oto
Otto
ovo
racificar
```

Fiz um código similar em Java e consegui, porem não estou conseguindo entender o porque da comparação não estar funcionado.

Comment: Uma coisa que notei em suas entradas é que você tem palavras com maiúsculas/minúsculas e, neste caso, a comparação dará diferente, o que não sei se é algo proposital ou não. Ex.: Omo. Idem para letras acentuadas. O problema com seu programa é que a função fgets incorpora o '\n' final da entrada à sua string, assim sua entrada ara terá comprimento 4 e ficará: s[0]='a', s[1]='r', s[2]='a' e s[3]='\n'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acontece que quando faz uma leitura com `fgets` pelo `stdin`, o enter que você pressiona é também armazenado como um `\n` dentro da string.

Veja como aparece correndo em debug e inserindo a palavra `aça`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou seja, na primeira comparação que existe no `for` feita com:

```
resp = resp && (s[i] == s[indc]);
```

Vai comparar a letra `a` com o `\n` e vai falhar de imediato.

Para corrigir basta eliminar o `\n` após ler com `fgets`. Tem muitas formas de fazer isto, mas fazendo o mais direto possível pode utilizar a função [`strcspn`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcspn/) que procura um caratere na string, no caso o `\n`:

```
do{
    fgets(entrada[numEntrada], TAMLINHA, stdin);
    entrada[numEntrada][strcspn(entrada[numEntrada], "\n")] = '\0'; //eliminar \n
} while (isFim(entrada[numEntrada++]) == false);
```

Com isto já funciona, como [pode ver no Ideone.](https://ideone.com/4g7tcm) Repare no entanto que nas palavras que tem carateres acentuados a verificação ficou incorreta indicando que não são palindromos. Isto tem a ver com o facto destas letras serem guardadas em UTF-8 e por isso o seu `ç` por exemplo, corresponde na verdade a 2 bytes e não 1:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esta situação já é mais complicada de corrigir e não o irei fazer nesta resposta, mas uma solução é optar por guardar a string como um array de [`wchar_t`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cwchar/wchar_t/), que corresponde a um *wide char* e normalmente lhe permite guardar carateres com mais de um byte em cada posição. Neste cenário é importante garantir que tem o *locale* correto, aplicado através da função `setlocale` definida em `locale.h`

Ainda assim gostava de fazer mais alguns comentários em relação ao seu código:

- Utilizar `strlen` duas vezes seguidas:

  ```
  int meio = strlen(s)/2;
  int indc = strlen(s) - 1;
  ```

  Não é o ideal pois acaba por fazer processamento repetido sem nenhuma vantagem. Melhor seria guardar o tamanho numa variável e utiliza-la duas vezes.
- Você pode incluir ambas as variáveis `i` e `indc` no mesmo `for`, definindo múltiplos inícios e múltiplos incrementos, que lhe dão uma sintaxe mais compacta:

  ```
  for (int i = 0, indc = strlen(s) - 1; i < meio && resp ; i++, indc--){
      resp = resp && (s[i] == s[indc]);
  }
  ```

  Aproveitei e inclui o `&& resp` na condição que faz com que o `for` pare mal uma letra seja diferente, evitando percorrer o resto da string quando já souber que não é palindromo.